# How to insert text into an Illustrator file using ExtendScript JavaScript

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, javascript

I opened my Illustrator file successfully using the below code:

```
var fileRef = new File("E:/project/AH_Portrait.ai");
var docRef = app.open (fileRef)
```

I want to write some text ("Handgloves") into it, but I'm unable to do so using the following code:

```
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
var doc = app.documents.add(null,width,height);
var text1 = doc.textFrames.pointText( [20,height-50] );
text1.contents = "Handgloves";
```

How can I write text in to my document?

Comment: Unable to write - what happens, do you get an error?

Comment: no my text(handgloves) opened into new file and illustrator(AH_Portrait.ai) file opened into another file

Comment: If you want to know more about the site, please read the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should spend some time on reading what you write:

```
var doc = app.documents.add(null,width,height);
```

reads:

1. from application
2. take the documents container
3. add a new document
4. that we shall call *doc* from now on

But that's not actually what you want to do you want to:

```
 var f = new File("E:/project/AH_Portrait.ai");
 var doc = app.open(f);
```

reads:

1. Find file
2. that we shall call *f*
3. open this file in application as document
4. let use call this document *doc* from now on

Ok, then the rest of the code works fine. However, there is a few caveats. The handle app is not universally defined to mean Illustrator! So usually you would put the line

```
#target illustrator
```

on the **first** line of your script. Second illustrator height coordinates are positive upwards. So `[20,height-50]` is actually above your image on most illustrator versions (yeah the 0, 0 used to be in lower left corner back in the day). You should probably do `[20,-height+50]` instead, but I'm not sure (possibly `[20, -50]`).

Now then your script becomes:

```
#target illustrator 

var height = 100;

var f = new File("E:/project/AH_Portrait.ai");
var doc = app.open (f)

var text1 = doc.textFrames.pointText( [20,-height+50] );
text1.contents = "Handgloves";
```

Off course this does not save your result.

Comment: but illustrator image only opened but the text cannot write over it..this line displays error  var text1 = doc.textFrames.pointText( [20,-height+50] );

Comment: i want to open illustrator image then i neet to write some text over it ..

Comment: @abdul what version of illustrator are you using? Is it possible that the file does not exist? In anycase we can only show you stuff that works for us. We can not debug for you. Illustrator documents arent images as such.

Comment: my illustrator version is cs6 .....actually i want to open a illustrator image then i need to write text over it..my code works fine but my problem is illustrator image and text opening in two documents...

Comment: @abdul Obviously thats what you told it to do!

Comment: please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: Oh btw there is an unobvious reason why your script might not work. The active layer is locked so it can not be wriyten into... But that is not exactly the scripts fault.

Comment: i cannot able to write into that file itself???Is there any way to write text into illustrator file??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59282/discussion-between-joojaa-and-abdul).

Comment: @joojaa btw locked layer was the issue :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37641978#37641978

Comment: how to make embed profile is true? i added saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true; 
 but it does not works

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're following the tutorial from https://github.com/jtnimoy/scripting-for-illustrator-tutorial

You need to define the document you want to write your text into. Instead, your code is creating a new document and writing the text on that.

You should use

`var doc = app.activeDocument;` instead of

`var doc = app.documents.add(null,width,height);`

if you want to write to the currently open document.

Comment: i changed my code now like this but the text(handgloves) opened into new file and illustrator opened into another file..

var width = 1280;
var height = 700;
var doc = app.documents.add(null,width,height);
var fileRef = new File("E:/phpbb_project_status/final changes/AH_Portrait.ai");
var docRef = app.open (fileRef)
var text1 = doc.textFrames.pointText( [20,height-50] );
text1.contents = "Handgloves";

Comment: Read your code. Read my answer. You're still using _app.documents.add(null,width,height)_ which will create A NEW document. Read.

Comment: ya please change my code and give me exact answer @Luciano